# Dokku / Postgres select query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, dokku

I need to run queries on a Postgres database/table running under Dokku.

I know this sounds simplistic, but this is not my wheelhouse.  I am a LAMP developer / DBA of 20+ years, so I know my way around SQL. My Ruby developer abandoned a project, and I need to access the data.  When querying "Dokku / Postgres select query" I get two results here on SO, and neither is relevant.  Google is not helpful at all. I have access to the terminal, but totally lost on how to run a simple query.

I use "dokku postgres" which gives a list of commands, none of which allow me to access a CLI similar to MySQL to allow me to run queries. Unless I'm blind.  TIA to anyone who can help.

Comment: `dokku enter my-app-name web rails db` which should launch [PSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html). https://dokku.com/docs/processes/entering-containers/

Comment: Thank you for this.  Now we just have to track down the password.